# Android MVP Architecture and Realm - How to Avoid Passing Context among the MVP layers?

Tags: android, realm, android-context, realm-mobile-platform, android-mvp

I have been learning Android MVP for awhile, in most of my Application, I find that it is not so practical to passing the **Context Data** among the MVP Layer for testability purposes.

However, for some cases, it is required to do so, for example, in order to access Realm database, I would need the **Context Data** for performing this implementation:

**Realm Implementation**

```
 Realm.init(mainContext)

        val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name(mainContext.getString(R.string.accountRealm))
                .build()

        realm = Realm.getInstance(config)
```

Only that I can perform the CRUD functionality of Realm.

Because of that I have to always pass the **Context Data** from View Layer to Model Layer which I believe which is not so practical.

**My Question:**

1. Is there any other way for me to implement the Realm functionality without the need to use the **Context Data**? How should I do it in the right way?
2. Is it okay/acceptable to keep passing **Context Data** or other similar android specific code among the MVP layer? Like for this Realm case, is it consider as an 'Acceptable Trade-off'?

Comment: Is there any reason why the Realm file name is a `String resource` instead of just for example `"wallet.realm"`?

Comment: @epicpandaforce I put it as String Resource, so that when it is necessary to change the name, i just have to edit the String.xml file instead of manually changing all function that have the same implementation.

Comment: You should probably just make a Public static final constant for this in your code, and you've suddenly removed your dependency on Context.

Comment: @epicpandaforce I'm sorry, what do you mean by "removed your dependency on Context"?

Answer (score 0):

There two flaws (if I may call so) in the code snippet.

**First.** `Realm.init(mainContext)` should be done in `onCreate()` of Application, just once.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Realm.init(this);
  }
}
```

Then add `MyApplication` to your `manifest.xml` file as below.

```
<application
  android:name=".MyApplication"
  <!--rest of properties-->
/>
```

**Second.** It's usually good idea to read static strings from resources, but not in all case. This case, for example, is an exception.

Create a java class to hold your database name as belowe:

```
public class AppStatics{
    public final static REALM_DATABASE_NAME = "myrealm.realm";
}
```

Then simply take database name from this class to set name for Realm database. . You don't have to configure Realm everytime.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Realm.init(this);
    RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name(mainContext.getString(R.string.accountRealm))
            .build()
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
  }
}
```

Now you can call instance of Realm by calling `Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();` in your Model (data operations module of MVP)